# Textbook recommendation for functional derivatives

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, general-relativity

I'm interested in understanding more about functional derivatives and how to perform calculus of variations on actions (e.g. in general relativity or QFT). What are the best references to gain a practical insight in how to vary actions with respect to some variables?

Answer (score 1):

I like the book Calculus of Variations by Jost and Li-Jost (see https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/calculus-variations?format=HB&isbn=9780521642033). The initial chapters of the book have a number of explicit computations. Later on, the book even has some material on calculus in Banach spaces which I found especially handy.